# Fetch Mime Type of Email Attachment in PHP 5.2 (imap_fetchmime equivilent)

Tags: php, email, imap, mime-types, mime

This question has been posed before but the user didn't give his/her full solution, so I was wondering if anyone else can help?

I need to be able to grab the MIME type of the attachment(s) which are part of an email message my script is reading from a mailbox.

I have the code below working fine, the thing is the server it needs to run on can't be upgraded (yet) to PHP 5.3.6 so I need either an equivalent or another workaround.

```
   $attachments = Array();
   for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($selectBoxDisplay);$j++) 
   {        
       $attachments["emailedDocument".$j]["name"] = $selectBoxDisplay[$j];
       $attachments["emailedDocument".$j]["content"] = imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($mbox,$msgno,$j+2));

       $mime_headers = imap_fetchmime($mbox,$msgno,$j+2);
       $contenttype = "Content-Type: ";
       $contenttypepos = strpos($mime_headers, $contenttype);
       $semicolon = strpos($mime_headers, ";");
       $attachments["emailedDocument".$j]["type"] = substr($mime_headers, $contenttypepos + strlen($contenttype), $semicolon - strlen($contenttype));

       // attachment filesize is the number of bytes in the content string
       $attachments["emailedDocument".$j]["size"] = strlen($attachments["emailedDocument".$j]["content"]);
   }
```

I've spent a while searching Google and not really come up with anything, so if anyone here can help I'd be very grateful :)